# Opening a binary file to Tkinter GUI directly

Tags: python, tkinter

with your help I have been able to create a Tkinter app that saves data using cPickle to binary and I am able to open this data back into the app using a simple drop-down cascade (File Open, File Save, etc).

My question is, in order for the user to open the data, they have to open the exe that I have created, select File-Open, navigate to the binary file and click it. Apparently this is too much for some and they want to open the file by double-clicking the binary file directly. I have saved the binary file in a fictitious .xxx format and I can associate the file to the exe app, however when I launch the file, it opens the Tkinter GUI but nothing happens. Clearly I have to call the open function in order to populate that data. Does anyone know of a way to do something like this? Is it even possible? A way to save data into the binary file and then when opened directly the script looks for a flag of sorts and I can call the open function or am I off base? Thanks

Update

```
def file_open():
"""Open saved .gsd binary file"""
designer_open_file = cleanpath
designer_open_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        defaultextension=".gsd",
        filetypes=(("GSD", "*.gsd"), ("All files", "*"))
    )
if designer_open_file is None:
    return

saved_gsd_data = pk.load(open(designer_open_file, "rb"))

Outside of function:

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
openfilepath = "".join(sys.argv[1:])
cleanpath = os.path.abspath(openfilepath)
root.after_idle(file_open)
```

Comment: For your case, you should treat the binary file as an argument to your application.  Check details on `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this simple example

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

def load_file():
    try:
        with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as data:
            text.insert(1.0,data.readlines())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist")

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root,width=80,height=40)
text.grid()

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    root.after_idle(load_file)

root.mainloop()
```

If the length of the arguments passed to the python script/executable are greater than 1 (meaning that there is more than just the name of the file we are executing) then I schedule tkinter to call the `load_file` function once the GUI has been drawn.

Then in the `load_file` function, I get the name of the file from the arguments and use this to open the file and do what ever is required.

(This has been tested as a python script rather than an executable since you haven't specified how you've built the executable)

Comment: Thank you both. I am using Pyinstaller for the exe. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Just a quick update/question. I wanted to just do a test before moving forward, I created a new exe that just prints a label with the data (from your code above). I get this: <_io.TextIOWrapper name = "my path\\filename="r" encoding="UTF-8>. Can you explain what the text.insert(1.0, data.readlines()) is doing as I am sure that is why I am getting this data back. I assume that I just need to strip out everything but the filename but I wanted to confirm. Thanks

Comment: Reading further, I now understand why I am getting the io.wrapper. Using your example, i am now in the process of passing the path to the function so thank you. While I am running into an issue, I'll post here if I complete it for others. Thanks again.

Comment: @EvanBecker Thanks for the update. If my answer has helped you, just click on the little tick to mark the question as answered.

Comment: I keep getting an error when I attempt to open the file. Testing using print, I know I am getting the full path to the file, I'll keep working at it. I edited the code above with the changes per your recommendation.

Comment: @EvanBecker Feel free to ask a new question to help you with the new problem. I believe I have answered your original question.